# How can i compute noise (1 sigma error) given a signal

Tags: standard-error, signal-processing, noise

I have a signal organized as an image, i.e. a matrix. Each "pixel" has an error $\sigma_{i,j}$. Simplifying, let's assume that the error is the same for all the involved "pixels".
How can I compute the corresponding noise associated to each pixel at 1 sigma error? Clearly, I'm assuming a gaussian distribution for the noise for each pixel.

Comment: Do you mean standard error or standard deviation. The two are not the same?

Comment: @Dave: sorry, i simply meant that the error on pixels is the same across the signal. It's only a simplification.